# Symfony 2.8 http_digest throws DaoAuthenticationProvider error

Tags: php, symfony

Hopefully I'm missing something here.

The following `security.yml` file works without issue in Symfony 2.3. However, upgrading to Symfony 2.8 throws this error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface
```

I've tested this on a fresh install of Symfony 2.8.2 and 2.3, having only changed the `security.yml` file.

**security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        my_in_memory_provider:
            memory: 
                users:
                    foo:
                        password: foo
                        roles: ROLE_USER
                    bar:
                        password: bar
                        roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            http_digest:
              key: %secret%
            anonymous: false
```

I've checked the upgrade path from 2.3 to 2.8 and nothing has jumped out at me as obviously being the problem. However searching online for the issue hasn't brought up much so I'm guessing I've missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found out this was a bug in Symfony 2.8.

Fixed here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17559